# Why I can't access the google-cloud-vision apis with PHP?

Tags: php, curl, google-api, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision

When I tested the google-vision-api, it showed below every time :

```
 Fatal error: Uncaught exception
 'Google\Cloud\Core\Exception\ServiceException' with message 'cURL
 error 7: (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)' in
 /Library/Server/Web/Data/Sites/localhost/gvision/vendor/google/cloud-core/RequestWrapper.php:245
 Stack trace: #0
 /Library/Server/Web/Data/Sites/localhost/gvision/vendor/google/cloud-core/RequestWrapper.php(150):
 Google\Cloud\Core\RequestWrapper->convertToGoogleException(Object(Google\Cloud\Core\Exception\ServiceException))
 #1 /Library/Server/Web/Data/Sites/localhost/gvision/vendor/google/cloud-core/RestTrait.php(96):
 Google\Cloud\Core\RequestWrapper->send(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request),
 Array) #2
 /Library/Server/Web/Data/Sites/localhost/gvision/vendor/google/cloud-vision/Connection/Rest.php(59):
 Google\Cloud\Vision\Connection\Rest->send('images', 'annotate', Array)
 #3 /Library/Server/Web/Data/Sites/localhost/gvision/vendor/google/cloud-vision/VisionClient.php(269):
 Google\Cloud\Vision\Connection\Rest->annotate(Array) #4
 /Library/Server/Web/Data/Sites/local in
 /Library/Server/Web/Data/Sites/localhost/gvision/vendor/google/cloud-core/RequestWrapper.php
 on line 245
```

I followed the step on this [page](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-php), and my code is just the example in google.

I'm in China now, but I have been using a VPN. It helps a lot if anybody can figure it out.

Comment: If you look up the error code, as the message already advised you to, you find this error described as "CURLE_COULDNT_CONNECT (7) - Failed to connect() to host or proxy." - so there is some sort of connectivity issue. _“I'm in China now”_ - well that’s likely part of it ...

Comment: Thanks for replying!But I can visit any google page with terminal and browser.It makes me feel uncertain whether it is because I'm in China.

Comment: Well maybe it’s not because of that, but some other reason ... but you’ll probably have to talk to the person in charge of the server andor network configuration to find out ...

Comment: I run it on my personal Macbook.All available means have been tried.Still I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured this out.The OS Server can't access the VPN.
This is what it's introduction says:It is a separately sold operating system add-on which provides additional server programs along with management and administration tools for macOS.
So I changed to use MAMP to replace it to set up a Apache server on my Mac.It works for me.